# yii2 mpdf render html reached max memory size

Tags: yii2, mpdf

I trying to render a very big pdf with mdpdf on Yii2 framework. 
I genereate an html page, but when i call the `render` function, php run out of memory.

I don't wanna expand the `memory_limit` ini settings (`256M` is more  than necessary).
I use this configuration, `$html` contains my huge code:

```
$pdf = new Pdf([
    'mode' => Pdf::MODE_CORE,  
    'content' => $html,
    'options' => [
        'title' => 'Report',
    ],        
    'marginHeader' => 2,

]);
return $pdf;
```

Maybe there's a way to render step to step the pdf?

Answer (score 0):

In Yii2 mpdf  the content is normally  a renderPartial for  a form layout 
and the renderPartial is populated  by one or more models that are the result of  query eg:

```
    $models = MyModel::find()->all();
    $content = $this->renderPartial('_mpdf_report_scheda',  [
            'model' => $models,
           ]);

$pdf = new Pdf([
    .......
    'content' => $content,
```

could be that in your case the result of the query retrieve to much rows so you could spliet you content in a part

eg: using limit() and offset()

```
    $models = MyModel::find()
    ->limit(20)
    ->all();

      $models = MyModel::find()
    ->limit(20)
    .>offset(20)
    ->all();
```

and launch the pdf for parts